# How to start Power Automate workflow from code/SPFX solution web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, spfx, power-automate

Is it possible to trigger start of Power Automate workflow and pass parameters to workflow through spfx solution/webpart on sharepoint (with React)?
Without premium connector.

I only found one way but it is premium connector and we can't use those.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without using premium connector - HTTP trigger.